# Live/Hot reload not working after adding React Native Map plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native

These are my dependencies

```
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
},
"dependencies": {
"native-base": "^0.5.4",
"react": "15.3.1",
"react-native": "0.32.0",
"react-native-drawer": "^2.2.6",
"react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.6",
"react-native-maps": "^0.8.0",
"react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
"rn-viewpager": "^1.1.3",
"color":"0.11.3",
"underscore":"1.8.3",
"fbemitter":"2.0.2",
"react-native-button":"1.6.0"
}
```

It was working fine before the installation of "react-native-maps": "^0.8.0"

Any ideas...**react-native-maps": "^0.8.0**

Comment: The app work but just don't auto reload ? May be it got disabled ? or it got stuck at Red Screen ?

Answer (score 0):

I have **react-native-maps:^0.8.0** installed and Hot Reloading working fine. Make sure you have **JS Dev Mode** is enabled in **Dev Settings**.